# hibernate searching on a large table very slow

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 3.3 on my struts2 project and database is Oracle 11g . In that I have a scenario of implementing [jQuery datatable](http://datatables.net/) searching on a table which has 16,000 rows (will be in Lakhs when goes for production). When I tested my hql and sql query with no 'where clause' on it, they took about 7 to 8 secs for 16000 rows. So I tried the same with JDBC connection it took just milliseconds to process it. Is there any other way to implement this with hibernate to optimize the fetching or should I proceed with JDBC connection for those kind of requirements?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for Hibernate to be significantly slower than a query over JDBC (assuming the same SQL).
But your tested Hibernate version is very old, lots of performance improvements (and bugfixes) where fixed in more recent versions, like *4.3.6.Final* (released later today).

So my guess would be that either you're not testing the same thing (for example, is your query via JDBC actually *fetching* data?) or hitting some old bug.
There where also multiple situations in which the JDBC drivers would be buggy.
If you are very unlucky you could be hitting a bug still present in latest version, but it's worth trying to update first.